# I can not view the XML in browser by xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, view

I am using the below mentioned codes in XML & XSLT

**XML:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wiley.xsl"?>
   <!DOCTYPE component PUBLIC "-//JWS//DTD WileyML 20110801 Vers 3Gv2.0//EN" "Wileyml3gv20-flat.dtd">
   <component xmlns="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley" version="2.0" type="serialArticle" xml:lang="en" xml:id="ecog473">
```

**XSLT:**

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
```

But the texts displaying without any styles (as text), and also it has broken in the end of document and display this error message.

**Error in IE ,**

> > Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.
> >
> > ---
> >
> > Use of default namespace declaration attribute in DTD not supported.

However, i can view the text in browser; when i am using this below.

**In XML:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <!--<!DOCTYPE component PUBLIC "-//JWS//DTD WileyML 20110801 Vers 3Gv2.0//EN" "Wileyml3gv20-flat.dtd">-->
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wiley.xsl"?>
   <component version="2.0" type="serialArticle" xml:lang="en" xml:id="ecog473">
```

deleted the ns in component tag (xmlns="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley")

How can i view with all the contents (DTD declaration, ns)?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that IE only supports XSLT version 1.0, not 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix when addressing the elements of the XML document (in the portions of the code that you haven't included in your post).

Answer (score -1):

You have open XSLT, this should work:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <xsl:output method="html"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```